# C# call stored MYSQL procedure with input parameter

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I'm calling stored procedure *finish_record* with 1 input parameter.
I read all related questions here for this topic but I didn't see mistake on my side...
But somewhere is it :-)

here procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `finish_record`(
IN recordId INT
)
BEGIN
UPDATE bnirolovani.record r INNER JOIN(
select Sum(SumError) as Total, count(RollID) as Rolls, sum(Lenght) as Lenght, sum(ExtraMeter) as ExtraMeter from bnirolovani.roll where RecordID=recordId)
i on r.RecordID = recordId SET r.SumError = i.Total, r.SumReels=i.Rolls,r.SumProduced=i.Lenght, r.SumExtraMeter=ExtraMeter;

UPDATE record r
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        SUM(Lenght) AS Total
    FROM
        bnirolovani.roll
    WHERE
        RecordID = recordId AND Quality = 0) i ON r.RecordID = recordId 
SET 
    r.QualityE = i.Total;
UPDATE record r
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        SUM(Lenght) AS Total
    FROM
        bnirolovani.roll
    WHERE
        RecordID = recordId AND Quality = 1) i ON r.RecordID = recordId 
SET 
    r.QualityII = i.Total;
UPDATE record r 
SET 
    DateProducedF = NOW()
WHERE
    r.RecordID = recordID;
END
```

and here my C# code

```
private void FinishRecord(int recordID)
        {
            try
            {
                string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                using (MySqlConnection conection = new MySqlConnection(con))
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("finish_record", conection))
                    {
                        
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("recordId", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value=recordID;
                        conection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
```

Could someone help me where is mistake? I didn't see it :-(
THX

Comment: So, "what's the problem"? If the SP only selects the input, the result is..? ie. what's the minimal failing case that generates this "problem", and *is* the "problem" encountered?

Comment: Does procedure run correctly from SQL Server Management Studio?  Is ID a primary key?  Is key already in database?  Update will only  work with a primary key that is in database.  You need to use Insert if key is not in database.

Comment: Hi procedure run correctly in MySQL workbench. In VS it fail with exception: "The data is null. This method or property cannot be called with null values."  @jdweng

Comment: Did you use same value of ID in workbench as c#?  Is you connection string using the same database that you are using when testing with workbench?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I replace C# code:
Add procedure call as simple CommandType=Command.Text instead of CommandType.Procedure
and works

```
 private void FinishRecord(int recordID)
        {
            try
            {
                string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
                using (MySqlConnection conection = new MySqlConnection(con))
                {
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = conection;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = String.Format("CALL finish_record({0})",recordID);
                        conection.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
            
        }
```